# Cannot change object property from other window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the main window, and another window. in the 2nd window i've created new `canvas`, and i want to change its properties from the main window, i've failed with this try:

this is the 2nd window's class:

```
public partial class window2 : Window
{
    public Canvas painting = new Canvas();

    public window2()
    {
    }
}
```

and here i try to change its property from the main window:

```
window2 paint = new window2();

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    paint.painting.Background = Brushes.Black;
}
```

when i click the button it does nothing.

**Edit:**

i think it would be better if i'll use the Application.current.properties and store the canvas object, but i don't know how to use it, i tried this:

```
Application.Current.Properties["p1"] = painting;
```

now how can i set properties from the main window with using the "p1" variable i've just created? i tried `p1.background` but i cant use p1 as variable, so how do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `window2` constructor should contain this:

```
this.AddChild(painting);
```

Whenever you create a new control (like `Canvas`) you should set its parent container.

This is my code from window2:

```
public Canvas painting = new Canvas();

public window2()
{
    this.AddChild(painting);
}
```

And mainwindow:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window2 w = new window2();
    w.Show();
    w.painting.Background = Brushes.Black;
}
```

What I believe you are saying is that you have an undetermined number of canvases and you want to access them all.  I suggest you keeping them in a `List` of canvases or in a `HashTable` (you need to use `System.Collections` namespace).  Also don't forget to set the parent container.

Comment: 1) it does not work
2) is there any way i could do this with Application.properties like i described above?

Comment: here is what happening: in the main window when i click the "new" button, a new window opens, and when i press ok in the new window, i add new item tab to the tab control that already in the main window, create new grid in the new tab's content, and create new canvas and put it into the grid. now i need to change the canvas property from the main window, but i cant use only one variable of canvas(the vairable that in the calss), so i thought if i can use the application.properties, to name every canvas that i create, so i can choose which canvas from the canvases i've made, i want to chagne.

Comment: To your second upadte, same goes here, i need to connect the new window with the main window

Answer (score 0):

A `Canvas` is a little odd as far as WPF controls go. It likely has a zero size, so you're not seeing the change. Try hard-coding a size to check whether the code is working. In the `window2` constructor do this:

```
painting.Width = 100;
painting.Height = 100;
```

Comment: No, i have all the other properties set, i just didnt write it because it was unnecessary